# Implementing Masked Text SMS into SOFTR Web APP

Tags: sms

I'm wanting to implement a way for my users to chat with each other while still tracking the conversations and masking their real phone numbers from each other. Airbnb, UBEr, etc do this well.....

Twilio has a tutorial, but it instantly went over my head since it seems to need a developer to write the code.... My question is, has anyone had experience with this? And If not, do you think it would be possible to implement this into my SOFTR app?

Here's the tutorial:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/masked-numbers

Also Twilio support gave me some other references too:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BhfNEoAm4NQ

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h7zyPTNC2bk

https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-are-masked-phone-numbers

https://www.twilio.com/docs/proxy

https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-is-masked-calling

https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/masked-numbers

Need developer help.